# numpy: minimal absolute value above threshold

Tags: numpy, vectorization, precision

From a multidimensional matrix I like to have the smallest absolute value above a tolerance value.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
matrix = np.random.randn(5,1,10)
tolerance = 0.1
np.amin(np.abs(matrix), axis=-1)
# array([[0.10321885],
#        [0.12167502],
#        [0.04575852],  # <- should not appear, as below tolerance
#        [0.15494743],
#        [0.21274028]])
```

Above code returns the absolute minimum over the last dimension. But I'd like to ignore small values (near 0) from determining the minimum. So in my example with `tolerance = 0.1` the third row should contain the second smallest value.

With `matrix[np.abs(matrix) >= tolerance]` I can select values above `tolerance` but this flattens the array and therefore `np.amin(...)` cannot determine the minimum for the last dimension any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the values smaller than 0.1 by for example 1, using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(np.abs(matrix)< 0.1,1,np.abs(matrix))
```

Then apply np.amin on top :

```
np.amin(np.where(np.abs(matrix)< 0.1,1,np.abs(matrix)),axis=-1)
```

Result:

```
array([[0.10321885],
       [0.12167502],
       [0.18718385],
       [0.15494743],
       [0.21274028]])
```

Comment: Yes, `np.where` with replacing does the trick. Wasn't aware of it. 
Although would recommend to use `np.nan` instead of `1` and `np.nanmin`. Would you like to update?